# Dynamically store multiple objects in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
const song = songs.map(song => song.title);

const playlist = [
        {
          url: `/music/${song[0]}.mp3`,
          title: `${song[0]}`
        },
        {
          url: `/music/${song[1]}.mp3`,
          title: `${song[1]}`
        },
        {
          url: `/music/${song[2]}.mp3`,
          title: `${song[2]}`
        }
      ];
```

I need to create dinamically `playlist` array of objects with as many items are in `songs` array without specifying them directly,
 something like this:

```
const playlist = [
    {
      url: `/music/${song}.mp3`,
      title: `${song}`
    }
];
```

How to approach this? Can i use `push` or `slice` methods?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Are you trying to build up `playlist` with as many items are in `song` array without specifying them directly?

Comment: Yes. I want create playlist array of objects with as many items are in songs array without specifying them directly.

Answer (score 3):

You already know about `map` that's the same as you'd use to create your `playlist`

```js
const song = ["Title1","Title2"] // result of songs.map(song => song.title);

const playlist = song.map(title => ({
   url: `/music/${title}.mp3`,
    title: `${title}`
}));

console.log(playlist);
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and clear. Accepted this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['song1', 'song2']
const newArr = []

arr.forEach(song => {
  newArr.push({
    url: `/music/${song}.mp3`,
    title: `${song}`
  })
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` over the `song` array and get `playlist` dynamically like this.

```
const playlist = song.map( s => ({
      url: `/music/${s}.mp3`,
      title: `${s}`
    });
);
```